# set map on center Angular 2

Tags: angular, google-maps

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="3.1390032 "  (triggerResize)="true" [longitude]="101.68685533 " [zoom]="zoom">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat?(lat): 3.139003 " [longitude]="101.686855 "  [markerDraggable]="true" (dragEnd)="loadCoordinates([ $event.coords.lat, $event.coords.lng ])"></agm-marker>
                      </agm-map>
```

I am using this module map centre not working marker show when I decrease the zoom.any help thanks
https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This was giving me grief too dude. Have a go at this fix that I found. Worked straight away for me. I implemented this.agmMap.triggerResize(); within ngOnChanges.

https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1101

Comment: While the links are helpful, it would be better to copy the relevant portions here in a formatted code block. [Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)